# How can i make a npm package that can be installed in global

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to make a npm package and can be installed as global,but when i publish a package,it can't be used in global,what should i do ?

I clone grunt-cli from github,I just want to test whether it can be installed in global,but i failed. What should i do?

Comment: What does "can't be used in global" mean? Anything can be installed globally, but without seeing any code, it will be hard to give more specific help.

Comment: ```javascript
  "bin": {
    "packageName": "./bin/packageName"
  }
```
when i add this code to package.json,i solve my problem. Thank for our answer,good luck  to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a package as a global package you need to run `npm install -g packagename`.

On Mac and Linux you need to run `sudo npm install -g packagename`.

Comment: I have solved my problem, but still I want to thank you